# How to implement Field Level Security in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am getting a problem in implementing Field Level Security in CRM 2011. I am very new to this technology hence not able to resolve this problem.

This is the steps i have done -

```
1.Created an Entity names Inquiry.
2.On Form Under Entity created a field named 'Password' with EnableSecurity set to 'true'.
3.Then Moved to Administration -> Field Security Profiles -> Created a Profile named    'Inquiry'. Under Users Tab selected a User(Mike) and kept the Field Permissions as it is i.e 'No'.
4.Now on Login for User(Mike) the 'Password' should be seen encrypted. but it does not display as  encrypted.
```

Steps used to Create User -

```
1.Under Users & groups created new user and assigned 'Service administrator'.
```

Please tell me if i missed out sum step or if i have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think user Mike has `System Administrator` security role.

This security gives always full access to all secured fields, you can find more information here:

[How Field Security Can Be Used to Control Access to Field Values in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309608.aspx)

section `Which Security Roles Allow You to See Secured Fields?`

Comment: @ GuidoPreito hey my System Administrator abc@DemoOrg172.onmicrosoft.com has Global Administrator as Security Role and user mike@DemoOrg172.onmicrosoft.com has Service Administrator as Security Role did u mean that both of them have full access and this is the reason it is nt seen encrypted???

Comment: there is no a default role called service administrator, maybe your is a custom role that has the administration privilege. try to assign to user mike another role as sales person or similar.

Comment: Preito Hey In office 365 Admin Center Under Users and Groups menu - > New User Created -> Settings ->Do you want this user to have administrator permissions? 
Yes/No
if i choose Yes There are several roles what role should i choose from there???
cos if i choose NO option the user is nt allowed to see the form itself.

Comment: you need to set the role inside CRM (Settings -> Administration -> Users -> select Mike -> and after in the left his Security Roles) not inside the office365

Comment: Preito ok. The problem that i am facing is -

The Form that i created comes under Extennsions menu.If after creating User i dont give adminstrative permission the Extensions menu is not visible.

and if i give user the administrator permission i.e 'Servics Administrator' then While choosing Roles from Manage Roles i get the below error -

Users who are grnted d Microsoft Office 365 Global administrator or Service administrator role cannot be removd frm d Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online System Administrator security role. u mst 1st remove the Microsft Office 365 role, and then try agn.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the solution to my question.Posting it so that it may help the beginners like me.

All i did was -

Steps used to Create User -

1.Under Users & groups created new user and did not give the user administrator permissions.
2.Then Under Settings->Administration-> Users -> Selected the user and opened the Form.
3.Then choose Manage Roles from Ribbon menus and selected 'System Customizer' as the Security Role.

1. Rest process same for applying field security.
   5.In the end logged in as a System Customizer and was able to see the changes.

Thank you @Guido Preito for the help.